# Uncaught jQuery 1.9.1 required. AjaxControlToolkit7.1213

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using asp.net and Ajax. The latest Ajax by default loads jQuery 1.10.2 from mircrosoft CDN, but I don't know why I keep having this errors as shown blow in console.

Errors:
Uncaught jQuery 1.9.1 required.
Uncaught ReferenceError: actJQuery is not defined.

Can anyone help me please? Also I'd like to know how to prevent ajax jquery from loading and using my own specific version of jquery?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Walther has [posted on his blog](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/12/14/ajax-control-toolkit-december-2013-release) about the most recent release and states:

> The Ajax Control Toolkit uses jQuery.noConflict() to avoid conflicting with an existing version of jQuery in a page.  The version of jQuery that the Ajax Control Toolkit uses is represented by a variable named actJQuery.  You can use actJQuery side-by-side with an existing version of jQuery in a page without conflict.

He goes on to explain how to keep "your own version of jQuery".

It also looks like one of the commenters on his blog has a very similar issue as you.  Stephen's response was:

> The Ajax Control Toolkit is using jQuery 1.9.1 and, if you try to force it to use another version of jQuery with the element, then it will throw an exception at you. Any chance that you added jQuery 1.10.2 to your page by accident? Also, remember that you must load jQuery 1.9.1 before the opening
>   tag.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I already comment out jquery 1.10.2, but somehow when I debug in local machine, Ajax still downloads a customized Jquery 1.10.2 from Ajax's microsoft CDN. So if it loads 1.10.2 by default, why does is saying actJquery or Jq1.9.1 is not defined?

Comment: Can't say for sure.  Take a close look at his blog post.  He goes into some good detail on how to resolve the issues he brings up.  It seems like your issue may be one of those.

Comment: Thanks for you link. i will look into it more. :)